# How do I show a message in the foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

A user goes to the URL:

http://mywebsite.com/index.php?company=walmart

Once the page loads i want to check if the registered user can access this people. To do that i check with an array save in session for the user.

```
Array ( [0] => ebgames [1] => walmart )
```

Using an `if/else statement` inside a for each loop i want to show a message or redirect.

`$_SESSION['accessto']` holds the array.

I tried this but no luck.

```
$companyname = $_GET['company'];
$accessto = $_SESSION['member_accessto'];
foreach ($accessto as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == $companyname) {
        echo 'You have access to this company page of "'.$companyname.'"';
    } else {
        header('Location:/login');
    }
}
```

`print_r($_SESSION['member_accessto']);` gives me the following

```
Array ( [0] => ebgames [1] => walmart )
```

Comment: Add `print_r($_SESSION['member_accessto']);` at the top and let us know what it outputs.  Also, check out in_array http://us1.php.net/in_array

Comment: i get this print_r($_SESSION['member_accessto']); gives me  Array ( [0] => ebgames [1] => walmart )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first make sure that `member_accessto` is set and not empty.

Other than that your code looks correct already.

```
session_start(); // needless to say ...

if (isset($_GET['company'])) {$companyname = $_GET['company'];}
else {header('Location:/404');}

if (!isset($_SESSION['member_accessto']) || empty($_SESSION['member_accessto'])) {
    header('Location:/login');
    exit;
}
$accessto = $_SESSION['member_accessto'];
foreach ($accessto as $site) {
    if ($site == $companyname) {
        echo "You have access to this company page of $site.";
    } else {
        header('Location:/login');
        exit;
    }
}
```

or

```
if (in_array($companyname, $accessto)) {
    echo "You have access to $companyname";
}
```

EDIT: thanks to your comment and @Barmar 's answer, looks like it depends on your site logic. If it's possible to load more than 1 company in a $_GET request, then the above logic means you need access to *every* site you try to access.

Comment: You are genius. Can't believe i missed that. Thank you. Have a good new years.

Answer (score 2):

Use `in_array`:

```
if (in_array($companyname, $_SESSION['member_accessto'])) {
    echo "You have access to this company page of $companyname";
} else {
    header('Location: /login');
}
```

The problem with your code is that you display the header even if there's a match, because the company name *won't* match some other element of the array.

Comment: Missing `)` in `if (in_array($companyname, $_session['member_accessto'])` ;-)

Comment: @Barmar hit the nail on the head... you don't break out of the loop on a successful match, so it just keeps continuing.  +1 for the catch! (btw, double quote at beginning of the echo statement to fix syntax)

Comment: This `$_session` should be in uppercase `$_SESSION` Barmar.

Comment: Oh, I said the double quote b/c the variable $companyname is inside the string.

Comment: Should it be doubles or singles @JeremyMiller

Comment: double quotes when using $variables within the string. single quotes will print it literally.

Comment: There was a mix of both in the original answer, so wasn't sure which one. Syntax highlighting gave it away. @JeremyMiller

Comment: @Fred-ii- good catch! sometimes syntax highlighting is the best error checker haha

Comment: I had a hard time at first, since there were 2 errors to start with, then the head scratcher was the quotes. @d-_-b

Comment: Sorry folks, not enough sleep last night.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to see if a single value is in an array. Use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in-array).

However note that case is important, as are any leading or trailing spaces. Use `var_dump` to find out the length of the strings too, and see if they fit.